# Getting Button in Android Search Dialog

Tags: java, android, search, dialog

how can I access the button on the left in androids search dialog?

http://developer.android.com/images/search/search-ui.png

In the picture above I want to set an onClickListener onto the books icon.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can do it easily. see the answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/44131089/3649347

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no way to do it. You could get to the layout and its elements if you had necessary ids. But the ids of the elements used by `SearchDialog` are not public, that's why you don't have access to them.